# Is there a general formula for the chromatic polynomial of power set graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Consider the set $A$ of $n$ elements and its power set $\mathcal{P}(n)$ represented as graph $H_n$ under the inclusion relation,

For example when $n=3$, $H_3$ would look like this (ignore the color).

[image]

is there a general formula for the chromatic polynomial of $H_n$ ( i.e. can be applied for different values of  $\ n$ ) ? Or an easy way to determine the chromatic polynomial of $H_n$ from $H_{n-1}$ ?

Comment: $[0] = \emptyset$ and $[n] = \{0,...,n-1\}$?

Comment: @Moritz yes....

Comment: Your graph $H_n$ has loops via $X \subseteq X$, correct?

Comment: @Moritz Not sure If I understood your comment. I edited the question to make it clear.

Comment: Can you be more formal with the definition of $H_n$ ?  In particular, why isn't there an edge between $\{a,b,c\}$ and $\{a\}$ ?  They should satisfy the inclusion relation.  Actually, it feels like you are rather working with hypercubes.  Does that ring a bell ?

Comment: @ManuelLafond Yes. It is certainly a hypercube. I do not know what's the common name of such graphs (boolean? hasse? lattice). An edge between $a$ and $b$ exists if they differ in one element and one is a subset of another.

Comment: Ah, so the "differ in one element" was the missing part.  The common name for $H_n$ is the $n$-dimensional hypercube.  See here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube_graph.  However, I couldn't find any results on its chromatic polynomial.  And it doesn't seem easy at first...

Comment: In the context of your vertex labelling, the $H_n$ are also often called the Hasse Diagrams of $(\mathcal{P}(n),\subset)$. But they are isomorphic to the hypercube graph of course. In any case, I answered a question a while ago where I needed the chromatic polynomials of these things, but as far as I could tell at the time, there is no known closed formula. Even Maple was unable to calculate it for $n=5$.